# Which option is more expensive when retrieving contacts form an Android phone?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is it possible to have an EditText box where the user starts typing a contact's name, and then a list of possible contacts appear, the user selects one and then the details of the selected contact is displayed.... WITHOUT first having to collect ALL contacts on the user's device?

From what I've found, you first have to retrieve ALL the contacts on the user's device, put that into a List and then read from that list rather than what I've described above.

What is more expensive - retrieving all contacts or asking for one at a time depending on what the user starts typing in that text box?

Comment: It depends on your specification. Wat is ur app doing with the contacts?

Comment: I want to add the details of contacts on the user's device, to my application. My application notifies listed contacts of something happening. The user can either complete a form to save a contact's details, or add a contact directly from his device.

Comment: If that is the case, you can import all the contact details in one go in the begining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say searching in database is slower compared to searching in memory.

**Case:** If the dataset is much bigger, this way could decrease performance, as more memory would be utilized.

In your case, there can be two possibilities:

1.) either you first retrieve all the contacts and then search in it

2.) fire a query to database for each character typed in edit text.

I think, expense and performance depends on size of dataset too.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how do you define expensive..

Reading all contacts to an array in RAM and looping through them is expensive in memory consumption.

Querying a database each time the user enters something is expensive in database transactions (whenever the data is cached in RAM or the database transaction is expensive in I/O depends is out of your control)